# iOS 7 Custom Container Controller - How to set Child Controller's view insets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, containers

I'm currently developing a custom Container Controller. The problem is: how can I properly set the content insets for the scroll views of my descendant childs?
Let's make an example. I'm making a Custom Container Controller (CCC) that has a translucent view at the bottom (like a TabBar), the child controller of my container controller is a Navigation Controller (NC) that has a Table View Controller (TVC) as a child. So the hierarchy is pretty straightforward:

```
[CCC]
  ↑
[NC]
  ↑
[TVC]
```

Now UINavigationController and UITabBarController already do this: they set the TVC contentInset to make them scroll under NavBar (or TabBar). But How can I achive the same behaviour?
I want my TVC (or whatever) to be 100% agnostic of its hierarchy, so I cannot make the TVC "manually" set its content insets.

The first solution I've implemented was to implement - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews into CCC and navigate the hierarchy looking for the leaf Controller checkin if its view is a ScrollView. It works fine, until I push another TableViewController (TVC2) inside NC. Doing so viewWillLayoutSubviews is not being called, and CCC cannot know of its child TVC2.

What's the strategy adopted inside UINavigationController and UITabBarController? Or how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think changing your own view controller's top and bottom layout guides should make it work as you expect. The problem is, setting the layout guides. As a "secret", the layout guides are actually implemented internally as `UIView` objects with 0 height. So technically, you can change the origins of the these views to suit your needs. Remember to set them correctly on each layout pass.

Comment: I tried to add to my custom container the method `- (id<UILayoutSupport>)bottomLayoutGuide` returning a custom `UIView` subclass that implements `UILayoutSupport`. The length method returns `90.0f` but nothing change. I've also noticed that translucent bars have a zero `bottomLayoutGuide`. So I think this is not the right way to do it.

Comment: Do not return a different view. Instead, obtain the system layout guide view and modify its frame.

Comment: Not working, the Table View is still hiding under custom "tabbar":
`UIView *bottomLayoutGuide = (UIView *)self.bottomLayoutGuide;
CGRect frame = bottomLayoutGuide.frame;
frame.size.height = 100;
bottomLayoutGuide.frame = frame;`